# how to give bounds while moving image on the screen

Tags: android, image, kotlin, motionevent

My image is moving on the screen but it is not bounded, i.e. it can go to upper side or right side or left side or down side and it disappears.
Also I want to toast the current position of image. How can I get it?

```
package com.example.viram.assignment
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams
import com.example.viram.assignment.R
import android.R.attr.data
import android.content.ClipData
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener
import android.view.DragEvent
import android.view.View.OnDragListener
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.widget.TextView

class imageposition : AppCompatActivity() {

    var img: ImageView? = null
    var xCoordinate: Float? = null
    var yCoordinate: Float? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageposition)
        img = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
        img?.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { view, event ->
            when (event.actionMasked) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    xCoordinate = view.x - event.rawX
                    yCoordinate = view.y - event.rawY
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> view.animate().x(event.rawX + 
                    xCoordinate as Float).y(event.rawY + yCoordinate as Float).setDuration(0).start()
                else -> return@OnTouchListener false
            }
            true
        })
    }
}
```